# Comments realtime updates in jquery, ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently creating a social network which involves the implimentation of a real time comment system.

I do not have problem generating the comments in php when the page loads. 
However, I do not know how I can update the individual comments div with jquery ajax. The reason is because they all have the same class, since they are the same design. These comments div can be many depending on how new posts are added using jquery and ajax.

Hence, is there a way in jquery, ajax that i can these individual comments div with the same which will also include comments for new post added to the page.

I am so confused right now.

I have something like this below

```
window.setInterval (function() {
$('.comment').    load('getnewcommentrefresh
 php', {$(this).attr('id')},     function(result) {
 $(this).append(result);
 });
}, 1000}
```

I am aiming for these code to grab all the posts comment div which as the same class as `'.comment'`. I intend to use `$('this).attt('id)` to get the post id and check for new comments and refresh the posts comment duvs.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Yes, there's a way. We'd need to see your code, though.

Comment: tutorial: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/